Rudin theorem $7.8$
There is the definition of $(D\mu)(x)$:

Accordingly, let us fix a dimension $k$, denote the open ball with center $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and radius $r>0$ by
$$B(x,r)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^k:\lvert y-x\rvert<r\}$$
(the absolute value indicates the euclidean metric, as in Sec. 2.19), associate to any complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ the quotients
$$(Q_r\mu)(x)=\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))},$$
where $m=m_k$ is Lebesgues measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$, and define the symmetric derivative of $\mu$ at $x$ to be
$$(D\mu)(x)=\lim_{r\to0}(Q_r\mu)(x)$$
at those points $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$ at which this limit exists.

There is the definition of Lebesgue points:

If $f \in L^{1}(\Bbb R^{k})$, any $x \in \Bbb R^{k}$ for which it is true that
$$ \lim_{r\to 0}  \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y) - f(x)|\  dm(y) = 0$$
is called a Lebesgue point of $f$

There is the theorem:
Suppose $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $R^k$, and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$. Let $f$ be the Radom-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $m$. Then $D\mu = f$ a.e. and $$\mu(E) = \int_E (D\mu)dm $$ ( mark this by $(1)$)
for all Borel sets $E \subset R^{k}$.
The Radon-Nikodym theorem asserts that $(1)$ holds with $f$ in place of $D\mu$. At any Lebesgue point $x$ of $f$, it follows that
$$f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} f dm = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))}. $$
Thus $(D\mu)(x)$ exists and equals $f(x)$ at every Lebesgue point of $f$, hence a.e.
I don't understand how do we get that $f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} f dm$ at any Lebesgue point $x$ of $f$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Let $x_{0}$ be a Lebesgue point of $f$. If $r>0$, then
\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{m(B_{r})}\int_{B(x_{0},r)} f \, {\rm d}m - f(x_{0}) \right| &= \left| \frac{1}{m(B_{r})}\int_{B(x_{0},r)} f \, {\rm d}m - \frac{1}{m(B_{r})} \int_{B(x_{0},r)} f(x_{0}) \, {\rm d}m (x) \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{1}{m(B_{r})}\int_{B(x_{0},r)} (f(x) - f(x_{0})) \, {\rm d}m(x) \right| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{m(B_{r})}\int_{B(x_{0},r)} |f(x) - f(x_{0})| \, {\rm d}m(x). \\
\end{align*}
As $x_{0}$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$,
$$\lim_{r\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{m(B_{r})}\int_{B(x_{0},r)} |f(x) - f(x_{0})| \, {\rm d}m(x) = 0,$$
and consequently it follows from the inequality obtained above that
$$\lim_{r\downarrow 0} \left| \frac{1}{m(B_{r})}\int_{B(x_{0},r)} f \, {\rm d}m - f(x_{0}) \right| = 0.$$
